# How to setup a static file server using django

Tags: python, django, web-services, web-applications, openshift

For the simple fact, I simply can't afford to use Amazon Web Services for serving static files.

I searched for a while and found that Redhat's [Openshift](http://openshift.com) is offering "Do It Yourself" PaaS. So, I am thinking to setup my own static file server.

The following are the things I am looking to have in it:

1. I want to upload/ delete files dynamically (without really editing code manually).
2. The site should be absolutely secure. (As secure as Amazon EC2 if possible)
3. I am looking to add a JSON responses so that I can do little magic easily (Ex: I can group some static files, search, know the count of static files.. )

So, I wonder if anyone could tell where should I probably start? are there any tutorials for that.

I am thinking to do this job using Django (as I am pretty good at it)...

Comment: Hint: there are many [static builder for django](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/static-builders/).

Comment: @jpic he is talking about setting up another server other than his project and providing admin interface of it to manage

Comment: yes, but it's always a good thing to test what has been done before getting started ... maybe even find some parts to reuse !

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a while since you've posted this question, but I thought I would let you know that we actually do have a django quickstart that will do everything you mentioned. If you're still intersted check out https://github.com/openshift/django-example.